# How to access Google Cloud Storage from App Engine in local development environment?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-platform

My code works perfectly on the deployed Google App Engine, but not when debugging it locally. The GcsFileMetadata returned is null, and gcsService.openReadChannel(gcsFilename, 0) gives FileNotFoundException, more details below. **To sum up, the problem is that the local app engine can't access google cloud storage. How do I fix that ? Any workarounds please ?**

**Here's the code**

```
GcsFilename gcsFilename = new GcsFilename(BUCKET_NAME, progress.imageName);

GcsFileMetadata gcsFileMetadata = gcsService.getMetadata(gcsFilename);

if (gcsFileMetadata == null) throw new Exception("gcsService.getMetadata(gcsFilename) returned null");

int fileSize = (int) gcsFileMetadata.getLength();

ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(5*1024*1024);
GcsInputChannel gcsInputChannel = gcsService.openReadChannel(gcsFilename, 0);
gcsInputChannel.read(byteBuffer);
```

gcsFileMetadata is null when debugged locally, but works fine when deployed. I comment it out and I get the following error at this line:

`GcsInputChannel gcsInputChannel = gcsService.openReadChannel(gcsFilename, 0);`

**Here's the error:**

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.dev.LocalRawGcsService@54381103: No such file: GcsFilename(cloudimagesbucketname, image_20150105_180444)
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you're saying. That particular line doesn't work when you try to upload from local dev to your production GCS? or simply the fact that this line doesn't work when debugging on dev? Prod and Devserver are very different (the devserver makes a bunch of abstraction to mimick production), especially in how they handle storage.

Comment: Yes. The line i mentioned doesnt work when I trybto upload from local dev to production GCS. I understand that pro and dev server are completely different. Question remains, how do you get that code working on devserver ? Is there such thing as dev GCS ?

Comment: there is such a thing as dev GCS, but it'll simply save the file to your local computer somewhere (I know for python you can setup that "somewhere" as an arg to your command line starting the devserver).  If the ultimate goal is to have the devserver to send something to your production GCS.... I'm pretty sure that can't be done.

Comment: The ultimate goal is to be able to debug that code i wrote above on devserver app engine. Is there devserver GCS for Java ?

Comment: hmmmm as far as I know, yes there should be a devserver GCS.  If your upload code really works flawlessly on App Engine, it might be a bug of the devserver though. I would file a bug on google's Public issue tracker (https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list) and see what they say there. Normally if it works on prod, it works in dev too

Comment: Thanks ill look for a dev GCS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No workaround to access Google Cloud Storage at localhost. You have to deploy your code at appengine and only after that you can access GCS services. This is secured service from google which can not be accesss at localhost.

Comment: Why is then Dataflow with DirectPipelineRunner (i.e. running on local) is able to write to GCS? E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35098770