# Google Dataflow hangs with no logs

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

When I run [example WordCount job](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/examples/WordCount.java) from Dataflow docs with *DataflowPipelineRunner, it launches workers and then just hangs with state Running.

Last two status messages:

```
Jan 29, 2016, 22:05:50
S02: (b959a12901787f4d): Executing operation ReadLines+WordCount.CountWords/ParDo(ExtractWords)+WordCount.CountWords/Count.PerElement/Init+WordCount.CountWords/Count.PerElement/Count.PerKey/GroupByKey+WordCount.CountWords/Count.PerElement/Count.PerKey/Combine.GroupedValues/Partial+WordCount.CountWords/Count.PerElement/Count.PerKey/GroupByKey/Reify+WordCount.CountWords/Count.PerElement/Count.PerKey/GroupByKey/Write

Jan 29, 2016, 22:06:42
(c3fc1276c0229a41): Workers have started successfully.
```

and that's it. When I click "Worker logs", it's completely empty. It stays like this for at least 20 minutes.

It works fine with DirectPipelineRunner (completes within seconds and creates output file on my gs://...).

What should I look at?

Command-line parameters:

```
--project=my-project
--stagingLocation=gs://my-project/dataflow/staging
```

Comment: Just to check, have you activated the Dataflow API?

Comment: Yes, Google Cloud Dataflow API is in list at 
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/enabled?project=<my-project>

Comment: Do you have any special firewall rules in place?

Comment: Could you include the job ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common cause of no logs showing up is that the Cloud Logging API hasn't been enabled. If all of the APIs listed in the [getting started guide](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/getting-started#APIs) are not enabled, then it could lead to both problems you described (no logging & hanging workers).

Try walking through through the getting started guide again and enabling all the relevant APIs.

Answer (score 1):

If all API's enabled, check once your user auth.

`glcoud auth login`

and

`gcloud auth application-default login`

Also, ensure you have run those command with the user has  `project owner or editor` access.

Else you can use the service account with your job as below

`import os
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = '<creds.json>'`