# Dataflow worker no activity

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm currently having an issue with Dataflow.

I have 2 projects on GCP and I tried to run the **Word Count** template in each project. One worked fine and another just stuck in `Running` state.

I checked the logging for both jobs in each project and on the job that stuck in `Running` state, there's no response from the worker, no log. On the job that can run normally, there's a log that states `Workers have started successfully.` which the other job could never reached and I can also see worker logs from inside this job.

I also checked Compute Engine for the job that stuck and saw that there is already an instance started for that job.

Any help would be much appreciated! Please let me know if there is any other info I can provide which will help.

Comment: Have you checked the worker startup logs?

Answer (score 1):

So it's because of my VPC configuration. I was messing around with it and added a firewall rule which denies ingress data, which makes Dataflow and GCE cannot communicate with each other (I guess). After I removed the firewall rule, Dataflow can now run normally.

Thank you all for your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In most scenario its seen that when user is unable to see any log ,following are the possible reasons:

1. Cloud Logging API hasn't been enabled for the project
2. APIs listed in the [getting started guide](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts#APIs) are not enabled

You should be able to see logs after enabling api.
If you have enabled you api and still not able to logs try steps below:

Check once your user auth by:

*glcoud auth login*

*gcloud auth application-default login*

Also, user which is running above mentioned command should have project owner or editor access

If you don's have project owner or editor access and you want to execute the above commands  use service account with the job as shown below:

```
import os
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = '<creds.json>'
```

Reference:

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35098770/google-dataflow-hangs-with-no-logs) is the similar reason what you encountered